# Bash file running fine manually but on cronjob stops

Tags: bash, cron

I've created a bash file that queries my database and then updates some tables.
When I run it manually everything goes smoothly but when I run it with a cronjob it  runs the first query and then stops before it goes into a loop.
After looking into it on the net I found a few things that may be the issue but from my side everything looks in order.
So what I did:

1. Checked if `#!/bin/bash` is included in my bash at the start and it is.
2. Checked that the path is correct in the cronjob. My cronjob below

   ```
   0-59/5 * * * * cd /path/path2/bashLocation/; ./bash.sh
   ```
3. The loop is in the format of

   ```
   for ID in ${IDS//,/ }
   do
       ...do something
   done
   ```

This works fine tested manually. My IDS are in string format that why I split it with `//,/`.(Works fine)

I log all outputs in a log file but it doesn't show any error.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or has any ideas how to fix the issue?

Comment: Could we see the whole script, please?

Comment: Without seeing the actual point where it breaks, I would guess that it might be permission related (if the crontab is set against a different user/sudo)

Comment: I found that the error was with the loop for some reason the cronjob doesn't support it and now Im trying to find a different approach for the loop. Im a bit confused with the sh and bash part. If I run my script as ./bash.sh and in my bash file I have set #!/bin/bash shouldn't it read and execute as a bash and not a sh?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the command you are running in cron has percent signs ('%'), they need to be escaped with a backslash. I've been bitten by this. From the manpage:  "Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash () ..."
2. The $PATH variable may be different when run from cron. Try putting something like this at the beginning of your script:  `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`
3. Try running bash explicitly, i.e. rather than `./bash.sh` in crontab, try `/bin/bash bash.sh`

Comment: I've tried the above but no difference I get an error  Bad substitution on the line of the loop. I only have % signs in dates for my logs but that doesn't affect the bash as they are printed fine in my log file.

Comment: I think to solve this, it is necessary to see the script that is causing the 'Bad substitution" error. If you don't want to publish the whole script, maybe you could pare it down to only the part that causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how helpful this may be to some people but I noticed when I `printenv shell` in my logs it printed that it was bin/sh even if I define it at the top of my script and run it as a bash file.

So what I did was changed all parts of my code that where not supported by shell and my conjob works fine.

So I assume that conjob does not support bash files. (Didn't find anything on the internet about this.)
Why it runs in /bin/sh I don't know.

Hope someone finds this helpful.